# Custom Default Terms&Conditions Checkbox in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm new to symfony and I'm trying to build my Sign up page. Generated the form and fields through my FormType, but I kind of want to change how the terms and conditions' checkbox looks.

It's label then box by default, and I want to reverse them and get my label on the right side of the box. Is there a way to sort this out?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're rendering your form in twig with `{{ form(form) }}`.

But you can decide, how the parts of the form get rendered, when you use something like this

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <div class="my-custom-class-for-errors">
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            {{ form_row(form.task) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col" id="some-custom-id">
            {{ form_row(form.dueDate) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

With this knowledge, you should be able to get your label on the right side.

Have a look at the documentation. There is a nice image, which describes the parts of the form, and how you can access/render it in twig.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html